# Compute the exterior dihedral angle between two hyperplanes

Tags: geometry, algorithms, computational-geometry

Let's say, in $d$-dimensional space, we have two hyperplanes: $\mathbf{n_1}\cdot\mathbf{x}+b_1=0$ and $\mathbf{n_2}\cdot\mathbf{x}+b_2=0$ respectively, and their normal directions satisfy $\Vert\mathbf{n_1}\Vert=1$ and $\Vert\mathbf{n_2}\Vert=1$. We define the exterior as the intersection of two positive hyperplane regions: $\{\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^d\mid\mathbf{n_1}\cdot\mathbf{x}+b_1\ge 0 \;\text{and} \; \mathbf{n_2}\cdot\mathbf{x}+b_2\ge 0\}$. We observe these two hyperplanes from the exterior, so the "exterior dihedral angle" could be <180°, =180°, or >180°. My question is how to determine the type of the angle?

[image: three types of angle]

The above figure illustrates the three types of "exterior dihedral angle" in 2D. We can of course observe their types in 2D by eyes only, but is there a computational method (e.g. an algorithm) to determinte their types in a general $d$-dimensional space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: hyperplanes should be half-hyperplanes intersecting at a ridge (e.g. the hinge point shown above).

I find an answer, it is surprisingly simple. Basic idea: we just sample two points respectively on each half-hyperplane, let's say, point $P_1$ and $P_2$, and we check if $P_1$ lies in the positive region of the second hyperplane, and if $P_2$ lies in the positive region of the first hyperplane, the other cases are invalid.

If they are both in positive regions, then the ange is <180°; and other cases can be similarly derived.